# How to quickly get email URL in Gmail with preview-pane?

Tags: gmail

I'm using the Lab feature *preview-pane* in Gmail.

How can I quickly get an email URL considering the URL bar does't change as I browse?

My best solution currently is to use *Show Original Message*, and use that URL, but while fast, the message is a bit verbose.

Comment: I suspect that any email url will be slow, other than the text-based 'original message' urls. The best solution would be if google had a less verbose equivalent to this.

Comment: If you shift-click on the message link it'll open in a pop-up window. That's the quickest way to get a direct URL that I am aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quickly is overstating it but if you press the *Print* button and remove everything after the first `?` to the last `=` and add `#inbox/` in between you have yourself a link that actually works.

For example `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?#inbox/111x11x5b93c0905`.

Sounds a bit complicated but takes about 10 seconds to do.